# How can one find all symbols in a binding form?

Tags: clojure

Given a binding form such as `[{a :a} {b :b}]` how can I find all the symbols? `(a b)`

Comment: Do `&` and `_` count?

Comment: ah, I hadn't considered them, but yes it seems I can just remove those from the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naïve approach would be to just treat the binding form as some nested collection, find all the symbols in that collection, and return the sequence of those symbols:

```
(defn symbols [x]
  (filter symbol? (tree-seq coll? seq x)))

(symbols '[{a :a} {b :b}])
;;=> (a b)
```

However, as [@amalloy noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128877/how-can-one-find-all-symbols-in-a-binding-form/38131043#comment63696500_38131043), this won't work in all cases. Here are some examples where the above implementation of `symbols` gives an undesirable result:

```
;; & isn't actually bound to anything
(symbols '[foo & bar])
;;=> (foo & bar)

;; duplicates
(symbols '{x :foo :or {x :bar}})
;;=> (x x)

;; keys and default values are evaluated, not bound
(symbols '{x (keyword "foo") :or {x (keyword 'bar)}})
;;=> (x keyword x keyword quote bar)

;; namespaced keywords and symbols don't work
(symbols '{:keys [::foo :bar/baz qux/quux]})
;;=> (qux/quux)
```

He suggests using the built-in [`destructure`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/destructure) function instead, but as he demonstrated in his answer, this causes some garbage to show up in the result:

```
(take-nth 2 (destructure '[{:keys [x]} (last y)]))
;;=> (map__10938 map__10938 x)
```

While this *technically* gives the list of symbols that Clojure will bind, that `map__10938` is just an implementation artifact, and has nothing to do with the destructuring language itself.

Thankfully, it's not too hard to parse the binding form manually and assemble a set of the symbols, taken from the original binding form, that would be bound:

```
(require '[clojure.set :as set])

(defn symbols [binding]
  (cond
    (symbol? binding)
    #{binding}

    (vector? binding)
    (apply set/union (map symbols (remove #{'& :as} binding)))

    (map? binding)
    (apply set/union
           (for [[k v] binding]
             (case k
               :or #{}
               :as #{v}
               (:keys :strs :syms) (set (map (comp symbol name) v))
               (symbols k))))))
```

Comment: This looks pretty good to me. You can simplify your `cond` quite a bit, to `(case k :or #{}, :as #{v}, (:keys :strs :syms) (set ...), (symbols k))`

Comment: @amalloy Cool, thanks! :) I didn't know you could do that with `case`.

Answer (score 1):

Much better is to use `clojure.core/destructure`, which understands which symbols are names that will be bound, rather than values that will be taken apart. For example, consider:

```
(let [{:keys [x]} (last y)]
  x)
```

In that context you almost certainly don't want to include `last` in the list of symbols, presuming that you are using this to better understand a destructuring spec. And if you call `destructure`, it tells you exactly what names will be bound to what values:

```
user> (destructure '[{:keys [x]} (last y)])
[map__10938 (last y)
 map__10938 (if (clojure.core/seq? map__10938)
              (clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/create (clojure.core/seq map__10938)) 
              map__10938) 
 x (clojure.core/get map__10938 :x)]
```

Now on the one hand you are getting a symbol that wasn't actually typed in by the caller, but that's probably still useful, because it tells you what Clojure will actually do to handle this `let` expression. To get just the left-hand side, ie the names that will be bound, you can use

```
(take-nth 2 (destructure '[{:keys [x]} (last y)]))
```

Comment: He's not asking to look at both halves of a binding (e.g. `[{:keys [x]} (last y)]`); he only wants to find the symbols in the *left* side of the binding. For instance, an expression might look like `(let [[{a :a} {b :b}] [{:a :foo} {:b :bar}]] [a b])`, but as he stated in his question, he only wants to look for symbols in the `[{a :a} {b :b}]` part.

Comment: Even if you only have the left half, some symbols can sneak in that are not names that will be bound. For example, `{:keys [x] :or {x (range 10)}}` - do you really want `range` returned from this function?

Comment: Ah, cool! I went back over the [Clojure destructuring guide](http://clojure.org/guides/destructuring), and it looks like there's a lot of stuff you can do with destructuring that I didn't know about. I edited my answer to reflect those complexities.