# How can I spec a hybrid map?

Tags: clojure, destructuring, clojure.spec

After writing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38129294/5044950), I was inspired to try to specify [Clojure's destructuring language](http://clojure.org/guides/destructuring) using [`spec`](http://clojure.org/guides/spec):

```
(require '[clojure.spec :as s])

(s/def ::binding (s/or :sym ::sym :assoc ::assoc :seq ::seq))

(s/def ::sym (s/and simple-symbol? (complement #{'&})))
```

The sequential destructuring part is easy to spec with a regex (so I'm ignoring it here), but I got stuck at associative destructuring. The most basic case is a map from binding forms to key expressions:

```
(s/def ::mappings (s/map-of ::binding ::s/any :conform-keys true))
```

But Clojure provides several special keys as well:

```
(s/def ::as ::sym)
(s/def ::or ::mappings)

(s/def ::ident-vec (s/coll-of ident? :kind vector?))
(s/def ::keys ::ident-vec)
(s/def ::strs ::ident-vec)
(s/def ::syms ::ident-vec)

(s/def ::opts (s/keys :opt-un [::as ::or ::keys ::strs ::syms]))
```

How can I create an `::assoc` spec for maps that could be created by merging together a map that conforms to `::mappings` and a map that conforms to `::opts`? I know that there's [`merge`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.spec-api.html#clojure.spec/merge):

```
(s/def ::assoc (s/merge ::opts ::mappings))
```

But this doesn't work, because `merge` is basically an analogue of [`and`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.spec-api.html#clojure.spec/and). I'm looking for something that's analogous to [`or`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.spec-api.html#clojure.spec/or), but for maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can spec hybrid maps using an `s/merge` of `s/keys` and `s/every` of the map as tuples. Here's a simpler example:

```
(s/def ::a keyword?)
(s/def ::b string?)
(s/def ::m
  (s/merge (s/keys :opt-un [::a ::b])
           (s/every (s/or :int (s/tuple int? int?)
                          :option (s/tuple keyword? any?))
                    :into {})))

(s/valid? ::m {1 2, 3 4, :a :foo, :b "abc"}) ;; true
```

This simpler formulation has several benefits over a conformer approach. Most importantly, it states the truth. Additionally, it should generate, conform, and unform without further effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `s/conformer` as an intermediate step in `s/and` to transform your map to the form that’s easy to validate:

```
(s/def ::assoc
  (s/and
    map?
    (s/conformer #(array-map
                    ::mappings (dissoc % :as :or :keys :strs :syms)
                    ::opts     (select-keys % [:as :or :keys :strs :syms])))
    (s/keys :opt [::mappings ::opts])))
```

That will get you from e.g.

```
{ key :key
  :as name }
```

to

```
{ ::mappings { key :key }
  ::opts     { :as name } }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was sure there was something like this that could be used. It seems pretty ugly, though; I hope that a more elegant solution is added in the future.